# Check Firstvisible item in ExpandableListView is Groupindicator?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to find whether the firstvisible item in the ExpandableListView is GroupIndicator view or a childView under it? plz help

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to do this

```
int firstVisibleItem =  mExpListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

long data = mExpListView.getExpandableListPosition(firstVisibleItem);
int type = mExpListView.getPackedPositionType(data);
if (type ==    ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
    Log.i("info", "childindicator");
}else
    Log.i("info", "groupindicator");
```